# Somehow (py)spark won't read my csv file right

Tags: dataframe, csv, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This is the Google Drive [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VZr12cJLOkbPheC3CSLonK1l6wibnY0o/view?usp=sharing) to my csv file (<100 kb, don't worry)

When I open it in Excel, everything was fine

[image]

But when I read it with `PySpark`, it just messes up. I think it's because of the Body column, which is a long and complex HTML string. Does you guy have any idea how to fix it? I've already changed the delimiter option but it didn't work.

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

questionDf = spark.read \
        .format('csv')\
        .option("header", "true") \
        .load("Questions.csv")

questionDf.select("*").filter(col("Id").isNotNull()).limit(100).show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two more options.

```
# When csv include newlines, parse 1 record that span across multiple lines
.option('multiLine', 'true')

# escape char that is used within quote-wrapped column. 
# ex: "hello ""xxx""!" => each side of xxx should have literal 1 double quote.
.option('escape', '"')
```